# The multi-part identifier "Maintenanceinfo.userid" could not be found

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to display details in a gridview from two tables and the login is tree structure, Admin, Manager, User

One table is Maintenanceinfo and the other is UserDetails

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub fillgrid()
        dt1 = Now.Year

        If Convert.ToString(Session("userType")).ToLower() = "admin" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=Maintenanceinfo.userid) AS userid, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo where year = " & dt1 & ""
        ElseIf Convert.ToString(Session("userType")).ToLower() = "manager" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=Maintenanceinfo.userid) AS userid, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo a,UserDetails b where a.userid=b.userid and b.Managerid= " & Session("userId") & " and year = " & dt1 & " "
        Else
            cmd.CommandText = "select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=Maintenanceinfo.userid) AS userid, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo with (nolock) where userid= " & Session("userId") & " and year = " & dt1 & ""
        End If

        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, Con)
        da.Fill(ds, "info")
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("info")

        GridView1.DataBind()
        '  cmd.CommandText = "select isnull(count(*),0) from DM_Memberinfo m inner join DM_Dln d on m.memberid=d.dlnmemid where d.memberid=" & Session("uname") & " "
    End Sub
```

The code works fine when trying to login as "admin" and "user" but when trying to login as "manager" it is not working and saying the "Maintenanceinfo.userid" could not be found

Appreciate if some one could help me

Thank you

Comment: You've got a query lower down that uses `INNER JOIN`, so you're obviously aware of them, so why are you using the old style `,` join in your second query? ANSI-style joins have existed in SQL for over 20 years! Also, if those `Session` values haven't been sanitized, *hello SQL injection!* You might want to look into using parameters.

Comment: yes I was using mix of new and old codes, the Inner join code was written by one of my friend which I have no ides about, anyways the issues is solved now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For manager part you have defined an alias for the Maintenanceinfo table. So you should use that or drop that alias:

```
    select sno, (SELECT UserName FROM UserDetails WHERE userid=a.userid) 
AS userid, Maintenance, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, 
September, October, November, December from Maintenanceinfo a,UserDetails b 
where a.userid=b.userid and b.Managerid= " & Session("userId") & " 
and year = " & dt1 & " "
```